# Jquery, fadein/fadeout causes multiple slider

Tags: jquery, slider

This is my scenario, I have a slider and a multiple image thumbnails at the bottom. The slider will auto rotate, upon clicking on the thumbnail image it will display on the slider.

Thumbnails and Sliders have, thesame size and I am using the thumbnail index as a reference to what I want to display. I am using jQuery fadein/fadein out to show hide the images.

My problem is after I have click on a thumbnail I have multiple sliders. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to solve this problem, or maybe an another approach to achieve, what i want.

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="show">
    <img src="image1.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image2.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image3.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image4.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image5.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image6.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image7.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image8.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav-thumbnails">
  <div class="show">
    <img src="image1.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image2.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image3.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image4.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image5.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image6.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image7.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="image8.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 524px;
  height: 371px;
}
 .slider div {
  width: 524px;
  height: 371px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.slider-nav-thumbnails {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 70px);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 14px;
}
.slider-nav-thumbnails div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

JS

```
let isSliderNavThumbnailClick = false;
function rotateImages() {
  if (!isSliderNavThumbnailClick) {
    $(".slider div.show")
      .attr("class", "hidden")
      .delay(3000)
      .fadeOut(400, function () {
        if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
          $(".slider div:first-child").attr("class", "show");
          $(".slider div:first-child").fadeIn(400);
        } else {
          $(this).next().attr("class", "show");
          $(this).next().fadeIn(400);
        }
        rotateImages();
      });
  }
}
rotateImages();

$(".slider-nav-thumbnails div").click(function (e) {
  let sliderShowDivNum        = $(".slider div.show").index();
  let clickNavThumbnailDivNum = $(this).index();

  if (clickNavThumbnailDivNum != sliderShowDivNum) {
    isSliderNavThumbnailClick = true;
    $(".slider div").css("display","none");
    $(".slider div").attr("class", "hidden");

    $(".slider div")
      .eq(clickNavThumbnailDivNum)
      .attr("class", "show")
      .css("display", "block");

    $(".slider div.show").fadeIn();
    isSliderNavThumbnailClick = false;
    rotateImages();
  }

  });
```

Comment: What kind of selector is `$("..slider div.show")` with two `..` ?

Comment: Typo. I have updated it